# handlebars js returns template code along with compiled code

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I'm using handlebars js - version 4.0.5.

This is my first hand with any templating engine. I'm using it along with jQuery.

I have created a external template file, and load the template when required using jQuery `.load()` as follows -

```
$("#sidebar-lists").load("/assets/template.html #emp-dep-lists", function(){
   var theTemplateScript = $("#emp-dep-lists").html();
   var theTemplate = Handlebars.compile(theTemplateScript);
   var context = data;
   var theCompiledHtml = theTemplate(context);
   $('ul#sidebar-lists').append(theCompiledHtml);
});
```

and this is my template code inside **template.html** --

```
<span id="emp-dep-lists">
    {{#each associateList}}
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                {{#if image}}
                    <img src="{{image}}" height="35" width="35">
                {{else}}
                    <img height="35" width="35" src="/assets/images/black-user-shape.svg">
                {{/if}}
                <span class="title">{{name}}</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    {{/each}}
</span>
```

I have created a `<ul>` on my page with a `<li>`. Now I'm trying to append more `<li>` into the same `<ul>`. Although everything goes smoother, but it replaces my first `<li>` and also it adds template code at first occurrence and then rendered `<li>`.

It gives the following result:

```
<ul id="sidebar-lists">
<span id="emp-dep-lists">
    {{#each associateList}}
        &lt;li&gt;
            &lt;a href="#"&gt;
                {{#if image}}
                    &lt;img src="{{image}}" height="35" width="35"&gt;
                {{else}}
                    &lt;img height="35" width="35" src="/assets/images/black-user-shape.svg"&gt;
                {{/if}}
                &lt;span class="title"&gt;{{name}}&lt;/span&gt;
            &lt;/a&gt;
        &lt;/li&gt;
    {{/each}}
</span>
<li>
  <a href="#">
    <img height="35" width="35" src="http://localhost:8084/assets/empImg/spot_1241.jpeg">
      <span class="title">John</span>
  </a>
</li>
</ul>
```